# Copying Google sheets data to newly inserted rows (which have been inserted by a script)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

We would like to extend an (amazing) script for Google Sheets that inserts multiple new rows in Google Sheets based on a cell value (original question and answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168797/307113)

As well as inserting the new rows, we also need to copy the data from columns A, B and T down to the newly inserted rows, from the source row of the newly inserted rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```
/**
* Inserts rows in the active sheet, copying content from the row above.
* Rows are inserted after every row where column X2:X contains a number.
* The number in column X2:X tells how many rows to insert after that row.
* The values in columns A, B and T on each row are copied to the newly
* inserted rows.
*
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function insertFilledRows() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 20 January 2023
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168864/269219
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  const columnsToFill = [
    1 - 1, // column A
    2 - 1, // column B
    20 - 1, // column T
  ];
  const values = range.getValues();
  const rowStart = range.getRow();
  const rowNumbers = [];
  const valuesToFill = [];
  const numRowsToInsert = values
    .map(row => row[24 - 1]) // column X
    .filter((value, rowIndex) => {
      if (typeof value === 'number' && value > 1) {
        rowNumbers.push(rowStart + rowIndex);
        const rowValues = values[rowIndex]
          .map((value, index) => columnsToFill.includes(index) ? value : null);
        valuesToFill.push(rowValues)
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .map(numRows => numRows - 1);
  const ss = range.getSheet().getParent();
  if (rowNumbers.length) {
    insertFilledRows_(range.getSheet(), rowNumbers, numRowsToInsert, valuesToFill);
    ss.toast(`Inserted rows in ${rowNumbers.length} places.`);
  } else {
    ss.toast(`Could not find any rows to insert.`);
  }
}


/**
* Inserts numRowsToInsert blank rows in sheet after rowNumbers.
* Fills the new rows with valuesToFill, one such subarray per inserted block.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet where to insert blank rows.
* @param {Number[]} rowNumbers The 1-indexed row numbers after which to insert blank rows.
* @param {Number[]} numRowsToInsert How many rows to insert after each rowNumbers.
* @param {Object[][]} valuesToFill The values to put into newly inserted rows.
*/
function insertFilledRows_(sheet, rowNumbers, numRowsToInsert, valuesToFill) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 20 January 2022
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168864/269219
  numRowsToInsert.reduceRight((_, numRows, index) => {
    const rowNumber = rowNumbers[index];
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(rowNumber, numRows);
    const filler = new Array(numRows).fill(valuesToFill[index]);
    sheet.getRange(rowNumber + 1, 1, filler.length, filler[0].length).setValues(filler);
  }, null);
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable - @doubleunary you're a wizard, thank you so much, worked first time!